# Delete an item from oneToMany relationship. Null value instead of removing

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have these entity

```
 class Centro {   
 /* ... */

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=NivelesEscolares::class, mappedBy="centro", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
 private $nivelesEscolares;
 /* ... */
 }
```

Center is linked to a OneToMany relationship with a NivelesEscolares entity. Here is the statement

```
 class NivelesEscolares
 {
 /*...*/

 /**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=App\Entity\Centro::class, inversedBy="nivelesEscolares")
  */
 private $centro;

 }
```

When I remove a center, the school level should be removed, but it becomes null instead. I already tried with orphanRemoval but it still doesn't remove anything. Also try with onDelete = "CASCADE" but it doesn't delete anything. I need help with OneToMany relationships.

Comment: How did you add the `onDelete = "CASCADE" ` annotation?

I usually add it in the JoinColumn annotation `@ORM\JoinColumn (onDelete="CASCADE")`


Also are you updating your database schema every time you change your entity class? you may need to run `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` to sync it up

Answer (score 0):

Well orphanRemoval and onDelete have a little differences as follow:

#### 1. `orphanRemoval="true"`

- the entity on the inverse side is deleted when the owning side entity is AND it is not connected to any other owning side entity anymore. ***Not exactly, this makes doctrine behave like it is not owned by an other entity, and thus remove it.***
- implementation in the ORM

#### 2. `onDelete="CASCADE"`

- this will add On Delete Cascade to the foreign key column IN THE DATABASE
- This strategy is a bit tricky to get right but can be `very powerful and fast`. (this is a quote from doctrine official tutorial... but haven't seen much more explaination)
- ORM has to do less work (compared to the two previous way of doing) and therefore should have better performance.
  if you want to delete the `NivelesEscolares` when you delete `Centro` well just use `onDelete` not `orphanRemoval` like this:
  **the `Centro` should looks like this:**

```
 class Centro {   
 /* ... */

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=NivelesEscolares::class, mappedBy="centro", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
 private $nivelesEscolares;
 /* ... */
 }
```

**and also use `onDelete` for `NivelesEscolares` with `@ORM\JoinColumn` like this:**

```
 class NivelesEscolares
 {
 /*...*/

 /**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=App\Entity\Centro::class, inversedBy="nivelesEscolares")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
  */
 private $centro;

 }
```

This will force doctrine to remove the 'school levels' as you said, Enjoy!